# How to check if the product is available from external API before being added to the cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a dropshipping webshop in Woocommerce that resells products from another company. I have managed to import the products into Woocommerce and keep them updated by using cron job every 4 hours.

Now I don't know how to set up a hook or action so that before the product is added to the cart, on the external API of the supplier is checked if that product is still really in stock.
Because we update the store every 4 hours it can happen that a product which is in my Woocommerce store is no longer available at the supplier. I also need to check that before checkout.

I can't find much examples online about it, I have managed to contact external API manually to see if the product exits but I don't know how to connect that with "woocommerce_before_cart" or some action like that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
/*woocommerce_add_to_cart is the hook*/
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
function custome_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) 
   {

      foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) 
     {
       
      //your code goes here...
     }
     }
}
```